# How to check whether the current URL has subdomain name using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, subdomain

I need to check whether the current URL has the subdomain name and if it has the subdomain, I want extract it from the URL.

Could anyone konw how to do this in the C# in an ASP.NET MVC app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
Uri fullPath = new Uri("http://subdomain.domain.topleveldomain/index.html");

string hostname = fullPath.Host; // returns "subdomain.domain.topleveldomain"

char[] separators = new char[]{'.'};

// returns {"subdomain","domain","topleveldomain"}
string[] domains = hostname.Split(separators); 

string subdomain = domains[0];
string domain = domains[1];
string tld = domains[2];
```

[String.Split documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx)

Note that you'll need to change it a bit if it's possible there will be more than one subdomain, I.E. `http://subsub.sub.dom.tld/` or something like that.

Comment: Yep, those pesky .co.uk domains messing up your schemes ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that, consider these examples, one is a domain and other is subdomain

> domain.co.uk
>
> subdomain.hp.hr

co.uk is United Kingdom TLD

and hp.hr could be Hewlett-Packard site registered in Croatia

Answer (score 0):

Subdomain in what sense exactly?

You could do:

```
Uri u = new Uri("http://sub.mydomain.com/path/file.htm");
if(i.Host == "sub.mydomain.com")
{ ... }
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: It is not any specific subdomain name I'm looking for. I need to check whether the URL has any subdomain name

Comment: But sub-domain from a particular domain? As in technically .com is the top level domain so mydomain is a subdomain :) If you want say anything under mydomain.com then just do a Regex match on [^.]+\.mydomain\.com and if it matches it has at least one sub domain off mydomain.com

Comment: Oh you want a $ at the end of the regex to match to end of the string ;)

Comment: Assuming that you do know the primary domain, you could do something like: if(u.split(".")[0] != "mydomain") { // it is a subdomain }.  You could also exclude "www" or anything else you don't want to match.  Note that my C# is rusty, so this may not be the exact right syntax...